# How can I use a javascript offset when linking to href's in HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, offset

I am building a website with a fixed place menubar that is 35 px high on top of my page. In that menu I have four items that link to sections down the page. When I click on the links the page jumps to that section, but the 35 px menubar covers the top of the text.

How can I modify this site so that when I jump down to a section it doesn't link me to the exact part of the HTML document, but 35 px higher to take into consideration the static menubar?

I am doing this with href code:

```
<a href="#links"><li>Links</li></a>
<h1><a name="links">Links</a></h1>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Menubar code

```
<div id="top-floating-bar"> <!-- Menubar -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column grid_12">
    <div class="fixed-bar-buttons">
      <ul>
        <a href="#top"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#links"><li>Links</li></a>            
        <a href="#resume"><li>Resume</li></a>
        <a href="#social"><li>Social</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- End the Menubar -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Description

You can use jQuery `.offset()` and `.scrollTop()` function

### Update after a discussion with tguidon

I don't know how your `top-floating-bar` css is defined, but i know what you want.
The size of the menubar in the fiddle is not right, because i dont know your definition.

#### Check out the [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6LBR/7/).

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"><
          $(function() {
            $(".goto").click(function() {
              var target = $(this).attr("href")
              target = target.substring(1,target.length);
              $(window).scrollTop($('a[name="'+target+'"]').offset().top - 35); 
              return false; 
            });
        });
    </script> 
</head>

<div id="top-floating-bar"> <!-- Menubar -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column grid_12">
    <div class="fixed-bar-buttons">
      <ul>
        <a href="#top" class="goto"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#links" class="goto"><li>Links</li></a>  
        <a href="#resume" class="goto"><li>Resume</li></a>
        <a href="#social" class="goto"><li>Social</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- End the Menubar -->

<br><br><br><br><br>
<a name="top"/> Top Section
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<a name="links"/> Links Section
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<a name="resume"/> Resume Section
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<a name="social"/> Social Section
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
- [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: ? Sorry i don't understand. Have you see the fiddle ?

Comment: Yea I saw the fiddle. Would I place the code "    $(window).scrollTop($('a[name="links"]').offset().top - 35);" in the <head> of the HTML file. It didn't work there before.

Comment: if you post the css definition for `top-floating-bar` i can build you an complete working sample

Comment: that "return false" bit prevents that scroll feature from being executed more than once

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your menu bar has a class `menubar`, you can try something like this:

```
$('.menubar a').click(function() {

  var y = $('a[name="'+$(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')+'"]').offset().top - 35;
  $(window).scrollTop(y);

  return false;

});
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work. I updated the top with the full code for my menubar. I implemented your code as a <script></script> in the <head>. Did I do that wrong?

Comment: Change `.menubar` to `.top-floating-bar` in the answer i gave and it should work. i.e. `$('.top-floating-bar a').click(...`

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working for me. I changed it to top-floating-bar and it's still covering the text. Should I not place the script in the head?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy, you could use this http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
It has an 'offset' option built in.